# Given a crash offset, .PDB, and source, how can I find the source line?

Tags: windows, debugging

I have a Windows Event Log entry giving the offset of the failed call triggering an application crash. I have a release build, the corresponding .PDB file, and the source.

I do not have a .MAP or .COD file.

How can I find the failing source line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

WinDbg has an `ln` command that will give you the nearest symbol of an address.

Open your binary using:

```
WinDbg -z somebin.dll
```

And in the command window, type:

```
ln <address>
```

Once you find the function it's in, run

```
uf somebin!SomeFunc
```

to find the closest line to the address.

Comment: According to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx?display=Print, "ln adr": will show the symbol nearest to that location.

Comment: Note that the address is the base of the module in WinDbg plus the offset of the crash location.  The ModLoad at startup for the DLL lists the base and end addresses for teh module (in my case. 0x10000000 to 0x10149000).  You can also use "lmDv" to list the loaded modules.

Comment: If I try to use WinDbg on a command line, it's not recognized.  I can launch WinDbg as an app, but then I see no way to open a DLL.

Comment: @JWWalker: File -> Open crash dump, then change to "All Files" file type. Using lm you can see module load address, using "ln (start_address+offset)" will display symbols around the offset.

Comment: @AndreiM, I don't have a crash dump, just an exception at a particular address.

Comment: If you change to "all files", then you can load the *exact* binary (exe, dll) for which the exception happened.